# Force window to only resize on one edge - OSX Lion

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, window-resize

As you know in 10.7 the windows can be resized by the user from all sides and corners. Is there any way to restrict the resizing of an NSWindow to only one side? Using `setMinSize:`and `setMaxSize:` won't do everything: by using those you can only restrain the resizing to *two* sides, not one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the cursor, track the mouse position use the `mouseMoved` event of an NSWindow subclass.  When it is close to the top, call setMinSize = setMaxSize = whatever size the window is.  When the mouse is closer to the bottom than the top, change the min size and max size back to whatever will let the user resize in the way you want them to.

Note that mouseMoved gets called whether the mouse is inside the window or outside of it (in my testing at least), as long as the window has focus.  But for this to work, first implement `-(BOOL) acceptsMouseMovedEvents { return YES; }` in your NSWindow subclass.

As an extra safeguard, you can intercept and prevent any attempts at resizing using `windowWillResize` (not `windowDidResize`) in an NSWindowDelegate.  From the Apple documentation:

> `-(NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize`
>
> ...
>
> The frameSize contains the size (in screen coordinates) sender will be resized to. To resize to a different size, simply return the desired size from this method; **to avoid resizing, return the current size**. sender’s minimum and maximum size constraints have already been applied when this method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification` and restore previously saved window frame if it was resized from the wrong side.

Comment: That might work, but I was aiming more for a solution (if it exists) that tells the window to only show the resizing cursor on one side of the window. Kinda like when you set the min and max width (for example) to the same value, the resizing cursor won't show when you are over the left or right edges of the window. In this case, to be precise, I only want the user to resize on the bottom edge of the window. I'm setting the min/max width to the same value, but the user can still resize on the top.

Comment: @Alex Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @Pascal no, it still shows the resize cursor. All I was able to do was to stop the resizing itself

Answer (score 0):

Window resizing behavior on any OS is really not your business.  You either support window resizing or you dont.  Its not your call to make how that happens except to support it or not.  Users would prefer you do.

And as an addendum no theres no decent way to do what you seem to want...by design.

Comment: I want to support window resizing, but there's a very good reason for only resizing on the bottom: this window is 'attached' to the menubar (like the app "Fantastical"). I want the user to only resize on the bottom edge. Why? Imagine the user pulls down on the bottom edge, making the window taller. Then he goes to the top edge of the window (the one close to the menubar) and puls down as well. The window gets shorter again, but hey! the top edge is no longer close/'attached' to the menubar, and the window is on the middle of the screen. You see now? Heh, I'll have to find another way...